# How to manipulate drawn objects with Model View Controller Pattern?

Tags: java, user-interface, model-view-controller

I've heard about MPV(Model View Controller) Pattern for complex GUI in java to manipulate objects drawn. But i'm new to MPV and can't really find anything that can help me to manipulate objects drawn that is:

1-To enable the objects drawn to move
2-To allow the re sizing of the objects drawn.

Can someone please help me to solve this? and tell me if i can also use MPV pattern to store those objects somewhere for future reuse; to be able to call a function or something to have details of those objects drawn?

Please help, am new to all these. 
This is my code:

```
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JColorChooser;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;

public class ERD_BUILDER_ extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -140274271716086522L;

    JMenuBar menubar;
    JMenu File, Exit;
    JMenuItem New, Open;
    JComponent DrawingBoard;

    JButton brushBut, lineBut, ellipseBut, rectBut, strokeBut, fillBut;

    // Slider used to change the transparency

    JSlider transSlider;

    JLabel transLabel;

    // Makes sure the float for transparency only shows 2 digits

    DecimalFormat dec = new DecimalFormat("#.##");

    // Contains all of the rules for drawing

    Graphics2D graphSettings;

    // Homework use graphSettings.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5F));
    // To change the stroke dynamically with a component

    // Going to be used to monitor what shape to draw next

    int currentAction = 1;

    // Transparency of the shape

    float transparentVal = 1.0f;

    // Default stroke and fill colors

    Color strokeColor = Color.RED, fillColor = Color.WHITE;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ERD_BUILDER_();
    }

    public ERD_BUILDER_() {
        // Define the defaults for the JFrame

        this.setSize(800, 600);
        this.setTitle("Java Paint");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setJMenuBar(menubar);

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();

        // Add the menubar to the frame
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        // Define and add two drop down menu to the menubar
        JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
        JMenu editMenu = new JMenu("Edit");
        JMenu dbMenu = new JMenu("Database");
        JMenu ToolsMenu = new JMenu("Tools");
        JMenu HelpMenu = new JMenu("Help");
        menuBar.add(fileMenu);
        menuBar.add(editMenu);
        menuBar.add(dbMenu);
        menuBar.add(ToolsMenu);
        menuBar.add(HelpMenu);
        // Create and add simple menu item to one of the drop down menu
        JMenuItem newAction = new JMenuItem("New Project");
        JMenuItem openAction = new JMenuItem("Open File");
        JMenuItem exitAction = new JMenuItem("Quit");
        JMenuItem cutAction = new JMenuItem("Cut");
        JMenuItem copyAction = new JMenuItem("Copy");
        JMenuItem pasteAction = new JMenuItem("Paste");
        JMenuItem UndoAction = new JMenuItem("Undo");
        JMenuItem RedoAction = new JMenuItem("Redo");
        JMenuItem clearAction = new JMenuItem("Clear");
        JMenuItem saveAction = new JMenuItem("Save");
        JMenuItem exportAction = new JMenuItem("Export");
        JMenuItem printAction = new JMenuItem("Print");
        JMenuItem ConvertAction = new JMenuItem("Convert To Tables");
        JMenuItem ColorAction = new JMenuItem("Color Picker");
        JMenuItem ZoomAction = new JMenuItem("Zoom");
        JMenuItem EntityAction = new JMenuItem("Entity & Attributes");
        JMenuItem RelationshipAction = new JMenuItem("Relationship Attributes");
        JMenuItem HelpAction = new JMenuItem("Help");
        JMenuItem AboutAction = new JMenuItem("About");

        fileMenu.add(newAction);
        fileMenu.addSeparator();
        fileMenu.add(openAction);
        fileMenu.addSeparator();
        fileMenu.add(saveAction);
        fileMenu.addSeparator();
        fileMenu.add(exportAction);
        fileMenu.addSeparator();
        fileMenu.add(printAction);
        fileMenu.addSeparator();
        fileMenu.add(exitAction);

        editMenu.add(UndoAction);
        editMenu.addSeparator();
        editMenu.add(RedoAction);
        editMenu.addSeparator();
        editMenu.add(cutAction);
        editMenu.addSeparator();
        editMenu.add(copyAction);
        editMenu.addSeparator();
        editMenu.add(pasteAction);
        editMenu.addSeparator();
        editMenu.add(clearAction);

        dbMenu.add(ConvertAction);

        ToolsMenu.add(ColorAction);
        ToolsMenu.addSeparator();
        ToolsMenu.add(ZoomAction);
        ToolsMenu.addSeparator();
        ToolsMenu.add(EntityAction);
        ToolsMenu.addSeparator();
        ToolsMenu.add(RelationshipAction);

        HelpMenu.add(HelpAction);
        HelpMenu.addSeparator();
        HelpMenu.add(AboutAction);

        newAction.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                new Lesson49_1().setVisible(true);
            }
        });

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();

        JPanel FieldPanel = new JPanel();

        // Swing box that will hold all the buttons

        Box theBox = Box.createVerticalBox();
        Box theBoxs = Box.createVerticalBox();

        // Make all the buttons in makeMeButtons by passing the
        // button icon.

        brushBut = makeMeButtons("./src/brush.png", 1);
        lineBut = makeMeButtons("./src/line.png", 2);
        ellipseBut = makeMeButtons("./src/ellipse.png", 3);
        rectBut = makeMeButtons("./src/rectangle.png", 4);

        // Make all the buttons in makeMeColorButton by passing the
        // button icon and true for stroke color or false for fill

        strokeBut = makeMeColorButton("./src/stroke.png", 5, true);
        fillBut = makeMeColorButton("./src/fill.png", 6, false);

        // Add the fields to the boxs


        JLabel Properties = new JLabel("Properties");

        theBoxs.add(Properties);


        theBox.add(brushBut);
        theBox.add(lineBut);
        theBox.add(ellipseBut);
        theBox.add(rectBut);
        theBox.add(strokeBut);
        theBox.add(fillBut);

        // Add the transparent label and slider

        transLabel = new JLabel("Transparent: 1");

        // Min value, Max value and starting value for slider

        transSlider = new JSlider(1, 99, 99);

        // Create an instance of ListenForEvents to handle events

        ListenForSlider lForSlider = new ListenForSlider();

        // Tell Java that you want to be alerted when an event
        // occurs on the slider

        transSlider.addChangeListener(lForSlider);

        //theBox.add(transLabel);
        //theBox.add(transSlider);

        buttonPanel.add(theBox);
        FieldPanel.add(theBoxs);

        this.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        this.add(FieldPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
        buttonPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,480));
        FieldPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,480));
        // Make the drawing area take up the rest of the frame

        // this.add(new DrawingBoard(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        final DrawingBoard drawPanel = new DrawingBoard();
        this.add(drawPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        exportAction.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(drawPanel.getWidth(),
                        drawPanel.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
                Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();
                drawPanel.paint(g);
                g.dispose();

                JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
                File theDirectory = new File("C:/Users/Wenda/Desktop");
                fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(theDirectory);
                FileNameExtensionFilter pngFilter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
                        "PNG file (*.png)", "png");
                fileChooser.addChoosableFileFilter(pngFilter);
                fileChooser.setFileFilter(pngFilter);

                int status = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(ERD_BUILDER_.this);

                if (status == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    try {
                        ImageIO.write(image, "png",
                                fileChooser.getSelectedFile());
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Image saved to "
                                + fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getName());
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }
        });

        // Show the frame

        this.setVisible(true);

    }

    // Spits out buttons based on the image supplied
    // actionNum represents each shape to be drawn

    public JButton makeMeButtons(String iconFile, final int actionNum) {
        JButton theBut = new JButton();
        Icon butIcon = new ImageIcon(iconFile);
        theBut.setIcon(butIcon);

        // Make the proper actionPerformed method execute when the
        // specific button is pressed

        theBut.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                currentAction = actionNum;

            }
        });

        return theBut;
    }

    // Spits out buttons based on the image supplied and
    // whether a stroke or fill is to be defined

    public JButton makeMeColorButton(String iconFile, final int actionNum,
            final boolean stroke) {
        JButton theBut = new JButton();
        Icon butIcon = new ImageIcon(iconFile);
        theBut.setIcon(butIcon);

        theBut.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                if (stroke) {

                    // JColorChooser is a popup that lets you pick a color

                    strokeColor = JColorChooser.showDialog(null,
                            "Pick a Stroke", Color.BLACK);
                } else {
                    fillColor = JColorChooser.showDialog(null, "Pick a Fill",
                            Color.WHITE);
                }

            }
        });

        return theBut;
    }

    public class DrawingBoard extends JComponent {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -4431176095451940075L;

        // ArrayLists that contain each shape drawn along with
        // that shapes stroke and fill
        ArrayList<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<Shape>();
        ArrayList<Color> shapeFill = new ArrayList<Color>();
        ArrayList<Color> shapeStroke = new ArrayList<Color>();
        ArrayList<Float> transPercent = new ArrayList<Float>();

        Point drawStart, drawEnd;

        // Monitors events on the drawing area of the frame

        public DrawingBoard() {

            this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

                    if (currentAction != 1) {

                        // When the mouse is pressed get x & y position

                        drawStart = new Point(e.getX(), e.getY());
                        drawEnd = drawStart;
                        repaint();

                    }

                }

                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

                    if (currentAction != 1) {

                        // Create a shape using the starting x & y
                        // and finishing x & y positions

                        Shape aShape = null;

                        if (currentAction == 2) {
                            aShape = drawLine(drawStart.x, drawStart.y,
                                    e.getX(), e.getY());
                        } else

                        if (currentAction == 3) {
                            aShape = drawEllipse(drawStart.x, drawStart.y,
                                    e.getX(), e.getY());
                        } else

                        if (currentAction == 4) {

                            // Create a new rectangle using x & y coordinates

                            aShape = drawRectangle(drawStart.x, drawStart.y,
                                    e.getX(), e.getY());
                        }

                        // Add shapes, fills and colors to there ArrayLists

                        shapes.add(aShape);
                        shapeFill.add(fillColor);
                        shapeStroke.add(strokeColor);

                        // Add transparency value to ArrayList

                        transPercent.add(transparentVal);

                        drawStart = null;
                        drawEnd = null;

                        // repaint the drawing area

                        repaint();

                    }

                }
            });

            this.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {

                public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {

                    // If this is a brush have shapes go on the screen quickly

                    if (currentAction == 1) {

                        int x = e.getX();
                        int y = e.getY();

                        Shape aShape = null;

                        // Make stroke and fill equal to eliminate the fact that
                        // this is an ellipse

                        strokeColor = fillColor;

                        aShape = drawBrush(x, y, 5, 5);

                        shapes.add(aShape);
                        shapeFill.add(fillColor);
                        shapeStroke.add(strokeColor);

                        // Add the transparency value

                        transPercent.add(transparentVal);
                    }

                    // Get the final x & y position after the mouse is dragged

                    drawEnd = new Point(e.getX(), e.getY());
                    repaint();
                }
            });
        }

        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            // Class used to define the shapes to be drawn

            graphSettings = (Graphics2D) g;

            // Antialiasing cleans up the jagged lines and defines rendering
            // rules

            graphSettings.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

            // Defines the line width of the stroke

            graphSettings.setStroke(new BasicStroke(4));

            // Iterators created to cycle through strokes and fills
            Iterator<Color> strokeCounter = shapeStroke.iterator();
            Iterator<Color> fillCounter = shapeFill.iterator();

            // Iterator for transparency

            Iterator<Float> transCounter = transPercent.iterator();

            for (Shape s : shapes) {

                // Sets the shapes transparency value

                graphSettings.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(
                        AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, transCounter.next()));

                // Grabs the next stroke from the color arraylist
                graphSettings.setPaint(strokeCounter.next());

                graphSettings.draw(s);

                // Grabs the next fill from the color arraylist
                graphSettings.setPaint(fillCounter.next());

                graphSettings.fill(s);
            }

            // Guide shape used for drawing
            if (drawStart != null && drawEnd != null) {
                // Makes the guide shape transparent

                graphSettings.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(
                        AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.40f));

                // Make guide shape gray for professional look

                graphSettings.setPaint(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

                Shape aShape = null;

                if (currentAction == 2) {
                    aShape = drawLine(drawStart.x, drawStart.y, drawEnd.x,
                            drawEnd.y);
                } else

                if (currentAction == 3) {
                    aShape = drawEllipse(drawStart.x, drawStart.y, drawEnd.x,
                            drawEnd.y);
                } else

                if (currentAction == 4) {

                    // Create a new rectangle using x & y coordinates

                    aShape = drawRectangle(drawStart.x, drawStart.y, drawEnd.x,
                            drawEnd.y);
                }

                graphSettings.draw(aShape);
            }
        }

        private Rectangle2D.Float drawRectangle(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
            // Get the top left hand corner for the shape
            // Math.min returns the points closest to 0

            int x = Math.min(x1, x2);
            int y = Math.min(y1, y2);

            // Gets the difference between the coordinates and

            int width = Math.abs(x1 - x2);
            int height = Math.abs(y1 - y2);

            return new Rectangle2D.Float(x, y, width, height);
        }

        // The other shapes will work similarly
        // More on this in the next tutorial

        private Ellipse2D.Float drawEllipse(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
            int x = Math.min(x1, x2);
            int y = Math.min(y1, y2);
            int width = Math.abs(x1 - x2);
            int height = Math.abs(y1 - y2);

            return new Ellipse2D.Float(x, y, width, height);
        }

        private Line2D.Float drawLine(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {

            return new Line2D.Float(x1, y1, x2, y2);
        }

        private Ellipse2D.Float drawBrush(int x1, int y1, int brushStrokeWidth,
                int brushStrokeHeight) {

            return new Ellipse2D.Float(x1, y1, brushStrokeWidth,
                    brushStrokeHeight);

        }

    }

    // Implements ActionListener so it can react to events on components

    private class ListenForSlider implements ChangeListener {

        // Called when the spinner is changed

        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {

            // Check if the source of the event was the button

            if (e.getSource() == transSlider) {

                // Change the value for the label next to the spinner
                // Use decimal format to make sure only 2 decimals are ever
                // displayed

                transLabel.setText("Transparent: "
                        + dec.format(transSlider.getValue() * .01));

                // Set the value for transparency for every shape drawn after

                transparentVal = (float) (transSlider.getValue() * .01);

            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: "MVC" is for Model View Controller. Did you mean Model View Presenter ("MVP")? Something else?

Comment: no i mean model view controller pattern used in java.

Comment: The term "MPV" != "MVC"

Answer (score 0):

You currently have 3 classes, Lesson49_1, .DrawingBoard, and ListenForSlider.

DrawingBoard is a view class, and ListenForSlider is a controller class.

The Lesson49_1 class is doing too many things.  Each class should either be a model, a view, or a controller class.  That's why the MVC pattern is used.  It allows you to focus on one small part of your GUI at a time.

In DrawingBoard, you have 4 ArrayLists having to do with drawing.  I don't understand the relationship between those 4 ArrayLists, but here's an example model class using the contents of the 4 ArrayLists.

```
package com.ggl.fse;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Shape;

public class ShapeModel {

    private float transPercent;

    private Color fillColor;
    private Color strokeColor;

    private Shape shape;

    public ShapeModel(Shape shape, Color fillColor, Color strokeColor,
            float transPercent) {
        this.shape = shape;
        this.fillColor = fillColor;
        this.strokeColor = strokeColor;
        this.transPercent = transPercent;
    }

    public float getTransPercent() {
        return transPercent;
    }

    public Color getFillColor() {
        return fillColor;
    }

    public Color getStrokeColor() {
        return strokeColor;
    }

    public Shape getShape() {
        return shape;
    }

}
```

Using this class, you can have one List<ShapeModel>.

In order to move a ShapeModel, you're going to have to store the X and Y of the origin of the shape.  By changing the X and Y, you change the location of the shape.

I can't really explain any more, because I don't understand all of your drawing code.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. the only way for me to allow the components to move is to use MVC? or is there any other ways of doing it

Comment: Or may be you can help me to split my codes and make it look less bulky? and add different classes ?

Comment: i'm quite confused and i dont understand what i should remove etc in my codes in order to call your class. Can you please help?

Comment: @WJCM: Could you add all of the button PNG images to your question so I can see what the buttons are supposed to do?

Comment: @WJCM: Ok, where are the PNG images? "./src/brush.png", "./src/line.png", etc.

Comment: The PNG images are in the source, i can't post them, i don't have enough reputation to do so. They are small images of 48x48. There are 5 buttons, The brush, the line, the ellipse, the rectangle, the stroke and the fill button.